# AngularJS model of select returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the current option of a `select`, but it returns me undefined (I expect it to return me an object).

Markup:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedLocal" ng-options="item.Nome for item in locais" ng-change="localSelectChange()">
        <option value="">Locais</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.locais = [{
        ID: 109,
        Nome: 'Aeroporto Internacional Hercilio Luz'
    }, {
        ID: 161,
        Nome: 'Koxixos'
    }, {
        ID: 184,
        Nome: 'Praça XV de Novembro'
    }];

    $scope.localSelectChange = function() {
        alert('$scope.selectedLocal: ' + $scope.selectedLocal); // returns undefined
    }
}
```

The curious part is I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacalves/Epaxq/) to reproduce the problem, with the EXACT same code, and it works.

**Update:**

I created a plunkr [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/oVAxHG/preview) where I replicate the issue.

The first select is wrapped on a div with its own controller "MyCtrl", and it works as expected, as I'm able to retrieve the model from the ng-change event handler function.

The second select "belongs" to the DashCtrl, the whole Dash tab view controller. When I try to retrieve the model from the ng-change event handler function it returns me undefined. Why is that?

Comment: See if the ng-app and ng-controller are declared in your application. Also verify if the angular lib is included in your project.

Comment: any reason for the -2?

Comment: does it return undefined or [object object] ?

Comment: @TiagoBarreto yes, it's all declared and included. everything works fine. the select is populated with data from the `locais` object, etc.

Comment: @ryan, it returns undefined.

Answer (score 13):

Try to change "$scope.selectedLocal.Nome" to "this.selectedLocal.Nome";

I had similar bugs when i try to use includes inside controllers... seams Scope is lost.

Comment: Helped me as well, I would also like to know: What is the issue with $scope here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need the declared object value.

```
    $scope.localSelectChange = function() {
            alert('$scope.selectedLocal: ' + $scope.selectedLocal.Nome);
    }
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Epaxq/6/)

Comment: That's what I was trying in the first place... it returns me the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nome' of undefined`  because $scope.selectedLocal is undefined

Comment: @zok show me the complete code because I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, Try using "track by" in ng-options

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedLocal" ng-options="item.Nome for item in locais track by item.ID" ng-change="localSelectChange()">
        <option value="">Locais</option>
    </select>
</div>
```